# URL Patterns and Views

Tags: python, html, django, rest

I have an application which requests data based on certain parameters. I use two functions to handle the requests and then create two objects from the responses. I am able to iterate through each object individually and display the data of a particular object on my webpage, but when I try to use both functions simultaneously, only one function iterates through the object. It is my understanding that this issue has something to do with URL patterns, but I am not as to what the best approach would be. Below you will find my urlpatterns, my functions, and the HTML I use to access the view.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.customer, name='customer'),
   path('', views.information, name='information'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def customer(request):
    for i, contact in enumerate(contactObj):
        try:
            contacts = contactObj
            context = {'contacts': contacts}
        except KeyError:
            print()
        return render(request, 'uccx/home.html', context)

def information(request):
    for i, ticket in enumerate(ticketObj):
        try:
            tickets = ticketObj
            context = {'tickets': tickets}
        except KeyError:
            print()
        return render(request, 'uccx/home.html', context)
```

**home.html**

```
<tbody>
    {% for ticket in tickets %}
       <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2'">
          <td> {{ ticket.id }} </td>
          <td> {{ ticket.company.name }} </td>
          <td> {{ ticket.summary }} </td>
       </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: The code you posted will encounter a `NameError` at runtime. Neither `contactObj` nor `ticketObj` is defined.

Comment: @ndmeiri I posted a snippet of code pertaining to the issue at hand, not my entire project, my objects are defined and the code functions as intended by itself.

Comment: you have to define different URLs for each view. currently, you have the same URL for both view so every time either you call to view by name `customer` or `information` this will always go to your customer view as it is defined above.

Comment: @GarrettMarschke Then post the code that defines the object, as that could pertain to the problem. Why bother including the body of a function when that body will crash upon execution? At the very least, you should have added a note in your original post that you included an abridged version of your view functions. Please consider reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL patterns should be different for every view. otherwise, it will always call the view which is defined above either you call it by `customer` or `information`

So your URL patterns should be

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('customer/', views.customer, name='customer'),
  path('information/', views.information, name='information'),
]
```

**UPDATE**

> You don't have to create separate views for fetching objects from different tables to
>   show in a webpage

Create a single view and send as many objects in context dictionary.

```
def table_content(request):
    ...     
    # fetch objects here from model
    contacts = Contact.objects.all()
    tickets = Ticket.objects.all()

    # set objects to context dictionary
    context = {'contacts': contacts, 'tickets' : tickets}

    return render(request, 'uccx/home.html', context)
```

Now in your template, you can easily loop over `tickets` and `contacts`

```
{% for ticket in tickets %}
   <tr>
      <td> {{ ticket.id }} </td>
      ... 
   </tr>
{% endfor %}

{% for contact in contacts %}
   <tr>
      <td> {{ contact.id }} </td>
      ... 
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Right, my question is how I should call a view with multiple functions and specify which function I want to use. The reason is because I have multiple tables on one webpage being populated from  different objects. So, for example, function1 creates obj1, and function2 creates obj2, and so on. How can I call both function1 and function2 to populate my different tables depending on whether I need data from obj1 or ob2 or objx...Thanks!

Comment: You need to have a single view, such can call as many functions as you like to assemble the data for the context dictionary.

Comment: @DanielRoseman how should I call my functions? I understand calling one function, but I am not sure how to add multiple functions to the url passed in urls.py. Currently, I have functions 'customer' and 'information' in views.py, and would like to call both functions on the same webpage in order to populate multiple sections of a table.

Comment: @GarrettMarschke check update section,  You don't have to create separate views for fetching objects from different tables to show in a webpage